# How to make a new class

Tags: html, css

I'm pretty new and still very wet behind the ears when it comes to css styling.

I have a class already defined .logo but I would like to create a second class "just for the logo image and background" from the Header template below"

```
<div id="container">
    <a name="top" id="top"></a>
    <div id="header">
        **<div class="logo"><a href="{$mybb->settings['bburl']}/index.php"><img src="{$theme['logo']}" alt="{$mybb->settings['bbname']}" title="{$mybb->settings['bbname']}" /></a></div>**
        <div class="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="{$mybb->settings['bburl']}/search.php"><img src="{$theme['imgdir']}/toplinks/search.gif" alt="" title="" />{$lang->toplinks_search}</a></li>
                <li><a href="{$mybb->settings['bburl']}/memberlist.php"><img src="{$theme['imgdir']}/toplinks/memberlist.gif" alt="" title="" />{$lang->toplinks_memberlist}</a></li>

                <li><a href="{$mybb->settings['bburl']}/misc.php?action=help"><img src="{$theme['imgdir']}/toplinks/help.gif" alt="" title="" />{$lang->toplinks_help}</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

I'm not sure how to take just the logo part and create a new class from the bolded part of the header code highlighted above. Thanks for any suggestions guys.

*edit for update*

Thanks for the responses so far guys. I think the problem is I don't really know how to describe the problem sufficiently.

Allow me to try and get a grip on explaining my actual situation.

I have two Divs which both have a drop shadow, by using padding I have allowed (deliberatly) them to overlap each other which looks great as it allow the image in one of the divs to slightly overlap the other div giving a 3d effect.

That works great so far except that due to both divs having a drop shadow, where the shadow overlaps there is a darker portion.

I've highlighted in the image the divs (which have css attached to them) and the darker portion where the drop shadows overlap.

I've tried using overflow: hidden but I'm not sure where I'm going with it if I'm perfectly honest.

[image here](http://www.thevapingforum.com/images/shadowsoverlap.png)

Thanks again guys, and I hope this makes a bit more sense... I think most of the time I'm confusing myself :)

Comment: It looks like the bolded part (in `**`?) *is* the `.logo` part, so what's the difference

Comment: The "duplicate" post linked above is not the same question. The moderators appear to have itchy trigger fingers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood you, you could just reference the image directly with this selector in your css:

```
.logo img
```

If that's not what you want please add more details to your question.

You can actually select every kind of HTML-Element you want just by calling it by its tag. e.g. `.logo a` or `.menu ul li`

Comment: Ok thanks for update on your question. It's very hard for me to solve this problem from what I have. Is it possible for you to give me a link to your site or provide a jsFiddle with the according code?

Comment: Hi lukasgeiter, I wasn't sure if I was allowed to post any links so hopefully it's not considered disrespectful, but the link to my site is http://www.thevapingforum.com

Comment: To show your problem, posting a link is totally ok. Ok my first idea would be to remove the box-shadow from the logo and the other div and to just put it on `#header`

Comment: I really don't know why I never thought of that! yes I think that will work. Thank you so much lukasgeiter, you won't believe how many hours I've been trying to figure this out and such an easy solution. Very much appreciated Thank you!

Comment: Quick update. Worked perfectly. I owe you a beer or ten :) Best wishes